# Why does Phoebe call Precious Susie?

Tags: dialogue, friends

In season 10 episode 1 of **FRIENDS**, Mike's girlfriend Susie comes to meet Mike at his home, then Phoebe and Susie have the following conversation:

> **Susie:** I mean are you guys getting back together or something?
>
> **Phoebe:** All right.
> Susie Can I call you Susie?
>
> **Susie**: My name is Precious.
>
> **Phoebe**: *I can't say that.*
> Susie, I'm gonna be straight with you. Mike and I are back together.

Why does Phoebe say that she can't call her precious? Am I missing something?

Comment: Because it's a ridiculous name that she picked for herself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It's a joke.**

Phoebe thinks it such a ridiculous name, that she simply won't call her it (and will call her Susie instead).

Look at her reaction below when she hears the name - she simply can't take it seriously:

Comment: Damn it Scott Lang!

Answer (score 4):

Because Precious is such a funny and weird name. As we can see in the video, Phoebe laughs first time on her name and then when Precious starts to cry she some how manages to call her Precious, fighting the urge to make fun of it.